# Phototropism or Hydrotropism is a more important factor for trees beside the lakes growing bending to the water?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I see a lot trees beside the lakes are growing bending to the water and I wonder why. After reading [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/how-do-trees-manage-to-grow-equally-in-all-directions?newreg=cf3168cc31b24eb3a5706d3558c2b3ea) I think it might be a combined effects by:

- Phototropism: the lake works as a mirror and sunlight are reflected
- Hydrotropism: of course, Hydrotropism...

But which one is a more important factor? Phototropism or Hydrotropism?